# Best transportation option for living 4 months in Vienna?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, austria, vienna

Starting from March I will be living in Vienna for 4 months. During this period, I have to go to work (15 min via U2) and come back every day during the week. Also, some weekends I would like to travel to other cities in Austria, and sometimes to nearby places outside of Austria, such as Bratislava.

What is the cheapest transportation option for me? Should I buy a like monthly ticket or yearly ticket, or ... ? I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: This question is about local travel, within and near one city, and has nothing to do with expatriates. (Other than that a long time local might have more knowledge than a newly moved in one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The monthly ticket for the public transport system in Vienna is 51 Euro.
The yearly ticket for the public transport system in Vienna is 365 Euro.
You can see the overview in German [here](https://www.wienerlinien.at/eportal3/ep/channelView.do/pageTypeId/66526/channelId/-46648). So 4 monthly tickets are cheaper, unless you make use of your right to cancel the yearly ticket for a fee (currently 22 Euro – so ~145 Euro with a yearly ticket, versus 204 Euro with monthly tickets).

If you just travel to the mayor cities you can look at the [Westbahn](https://westbahn.at/en). 
If you want to go to other places by train you have to use the [ÖBB](https://www.oebb.at/en/). There are [customer cards](https://www.oebb.at/en/tickets-kundenkarten/kundenkarten) if you travel a lot you can save alot of money with them.

Comment: So 51 Euro monthly for travel to everywhere inside Austria?

Comment: 51 Euro/Months for traveling within Vienna

Comment: Is there any monthly ticket for traveling within Austria?

Comment: Also, is the Vienna airport considered within Vienna? Can I buy a monthly ticket at the airport?

Comment: Add1: No. You can by a yearly ticket for ÖBB for over 1000 Euro. But if you are just traveling with Westbahn you can by a ticket. But this is only worth it if you travel a lot. So it is probably not worth it.

Comment: Add2: No. If you take the ÖBB it costs about 2 Euros if you have a monthly ticket for the public transport system in Vienna.

Comment: So from the airport I can get a monthly ticket and then with 2 euros I can take ÖBB to all stations or just to the central station?

Comment: Yes. But If I were you I would by the monthly ticket online. This way you can print your ticket multiple times (If you loose it or it gets damaged)